# Selenium server try to launch Safari browser for a Firefox test

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem using a selenium server started with the selenium-maven-plugin. The server start normally with the command

```
mvn selenium:start-server
```

Then, I run the following test :

```java
@Test
public void simpleTest() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/todolist-web/todo");
    Assert.assertEquals("Todos", driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
}
```

I get the following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Safari could not be found in the path! Please add the directory containing ''Safari.exe'' to your PATH environment variable, or explicitly specify a path to Safari like this: safari c:\blah\Safari.exe`

It's true that Safari is not installed on my computer but, as you can see, I ran a Firefox test. So why is it looking for Safari browser ?

My pom.xml contains 2 jar :

```
 - org.seleniumhq.selenium selenium-server 2.31.0  
 - org.seleniumhq.selenium selenium-firefox-driver 2.31.0
```

Please note it works correctly if I use the following code (added before my `simpleTest()`) instead of the maven command to launch the selenium server.

```java
private static SeleniumServer server;
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpTest() throws Exception {
    RemoteControlConfiguration conf = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
    conf.setPort(4444);
    conf.setDebugURL("/wd/hub");
    server = new SeleniumServer(conf);
    server.start();
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownTest() {
    server.stop();
}
```

Comment: Can you try  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver() instead and see what happens?